# Is there a color scheme that colors variables?

Tags: python, colors, editor, themes, sublimetext

Ok, I use Sublime Text and code Python, but I guess this question works for any language in any editor.
Generally, color schemes give colors to unimportant words like "in", "or" or "def". They don't color variables. I am trying to find a color scheme (for sublime text, if possible) that gives more importance to variables and less importance to regular language connectors.

I believe that from a language point of view this makes sense. When a programmer reads code, it is supposed to be like reading regular language. But coloring simple words and not coloring variables does not help, for example:

*One* ring **to** bring *them* all

**and in the** darkness bind *them.*

highlights the unimportant words, on the other hand:

*One* **ring** to **bring** *them* **all**

and in the **darkness bind** *them.*

Highlights the important ones and makes it easier to read. You could even read only the bold words and you would know what the sentence is about:

ring - bring - all - darkness - bind

I am kind of new to programming (one year), and maybe someone who designs color schemes can prove me wrong, but I've studied language and at least in regular languages this makes sense.

So, if anyone knows a theme that colors variables I will thank him for sharing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Color Coder](https://github.com/vprimachenko/Sublime-Colorcoder) is a sublime text plugin which seems to support what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is called semantic highlight. [Netbeans supports it](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Python#Semantic_highlighting) , you may find something more googling now that you know the name.